# jQuery Client-Side Text Input Previews: Parsing

Tags: jquery, parsing, text, textarea, preview

For the sake of learning more about jQuery, I was wondering if anyone could show me how to make a reaaallly simple parser in jQuery. All I would want the parser to do is take a post from a user and wherever the user has input a line break, make paragraphs.

Example: The user types two lines of a message:

```
 This is the first line.

 This is the second line.
```

What I would want out:

```
 <p>This is the first line.</p>

 <p>This is the second line.</p>
```

Let's say I define the parser as simpleParser (which currently doesn't alter the text):

```
 function simpleParser(text_input) {
      return text_input
 }
```

And it's called as such:

```
 $('.textarea').bind('keyup', function() {
    var post = $(this).val()
    $('#textarea .preview').html(textileParser(post));
});
```

I know that I can rely on premade WYSIWYG and other editors that others have created, but as an experiment in learning more jQuery, can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why would you need jQuery to parse a string? jQuery description: 'jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development.'

Comment: well, if you are going to preview a post on a page you have two options - one is to have jQuery call a controller to parse the string (in rails, anyway), and the other is to have jQuery parse the string on the client side. the first sends many more requests to your server, especially if you want a live preview on every keyup.

Comment: There's no condition or regex involved, though, which really limits the applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function parseText(str){
    return "<p>" + str.split("\n").join("</p><p>") + "</p>";
}
```

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QKf3q/1/